# get a position as tag from ViewHolder Android

Tags: listview, android-intent, view, get, custom-adapter

i'm trying to start a new activity from a listview. i'm loadind some data from database and open it in another activity...works fine when i use OnItemClickListener and getTag from my customAdapter...but the results  showed duplicated in some itens on listview. Searching on some topics...i found the resource ViewHolder.

It solved the duplication problem, but i cannot start the new activity from holder.getTag().

My view holder

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView hs;
    TextView hi;
    TextView ha;
    ImageView ho;
    ImageView hm;   
}
```

My customAdapter view code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    DataAdapter.ItemLista item = itens.get(position);
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_listview, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.hi = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.id);
        holder.hs = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.musica);
        holder.ha = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cantor);
        holder.ho = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_oracao);
        holder.hm = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_missa);


        /*if (imgMissa.equals(null)) {
            missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("louvor")) {
            missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.louvor);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("adoracao")) {
            missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.adoracao);
        }*/
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        Log.v(String.valueOf(holder),"valor do setholder");
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Log.v(String.valueOf(holder),"valor do getholder");
    }
    holder.hi.setText(String.valueOf(item.id));
    holder.hs.setText(item.musica);
    holder.ha.setText(item.cantor);
    String imgOra = item.oracao;

    if (imgOra.equals(null)) {
        holder.ho.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
    }else if(imgOra.equals("louvor")) {
        holder.ho.setImageResource(R.drawable.louvor);
    }else if(imgOra.equals("adoracao")) {
        holder.ho.setImageResource(R.drawable.adoracao);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

In this case i need to get the field holder.hi as tag. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue adding a intent inside the custom adapter instead of fragment. So for it works i had to change some parts of the code adding a String[] and a Context. Below is the solution that i found. Hope it help future doubts.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataAdapter.ItemLista> itens;
    DataAdapter.ItemLista item;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context contexto, List<DataAdapter.ItemLista> itens) {
        super();    
        this.itens = itens;
        this.context = contexto;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
.
.
.
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String[] extra = new String[itens.size()];
        item = itens.get(position);
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.hi = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.id);
            holder.hs = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.musica);
            holder.ha = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cantor);
            holder.ho = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_oracao);
            holder.hm = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_missa);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.hi.setText(String.valueOf(item.id));
        holder.hs.setText(item.musica);
        holder.ha.setText(item.cantor);
        extra[position] = String.valueOf(item.id);
        String imgOra = item.oracao;
        if (imgOra.equals(null)) {
            holder.ho.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("louvor")) {
            holder.ho.setImageResource(R.drawable.louvor);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("adoracao")) {
            holder.ho.setImageResource(R.drawable.adoracao);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mostraLetra = new Intent();
                mostraLetra.setClass(context, ExibeMusica.class);
                mostraLetra.putExtra("id",extra[position]);
                context.startActivity(mostraLetra);
            }
         });
         return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Does this realy work? the onClick listener doesn't occurs when you know the "position" variable